# Emails not been triggered using microsoft graph API when the total attachments length exceeds 4MB

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I am using graph API v1.0 to send email to end users. But in one of the scenario I am facing issue where end user is not receiving any email when the total attachments size exceeds 4 MB. There are multiple attachments of 10 number where all most of them are less than 1 MB and one attachment is 2 MB. what do I need to do in case I need to send email. Seen many posts where Upload session is useful only when attachments size is higher than 3 MB. But here the case is different. What should be the solution for this?

Comment: Which Graph API call you're using for the above scenario? What error that you're getting?

Comment: In addition to that, check with your administrator whether they enabled any attachment size limits at their end. Alternately try sending email outside of Graph API, just send email attachment using Outlook and see if it allows you to send more than 4MB.